# loading navigation properties with raw sql query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    t.ServerId, t.Id, s.Name
FROM 
    MyTable as t
JOIN 
    Server s ON t.ServerId = S.Id
```

I'm running it with:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<entity>("query_goes_here");
```

How can I configure EF so that it loads the `Server` property of  my entity with the return data from the query?

Based on the answer by @octavioccl, I ended up doing this:

```
foreach(var result in results)
{
    context.Attach(result);
    context.Entry(result).Reference(p => p.Server).Load();
}
```

But I'm afraid this is making a lot of db trips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`DbSet.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) method for queries that return entity types. The returned objects must be of the type expected by the `DbSet` object, and *they are automatically tracked by the database context* unless you turn tracking off.

```
var enties= _context.Entities.SqlQuery("query_goes_here");
```

After execute your query, you should be able of get the `Server` through your `entity` instance via lazy loading:

```
var server=entity.Server;
```

---

On the other hand, the returned data by the [`Database.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601%28System.String,System.Object[]%29) isn't tracked by the database context, even if you use this method to retrieve entity types. If you want to track the entities that you get after execute your query using this method, you can try this:

```
//Attach the entity to the DbContext
_context.Entities.Attach(entity);

//The Server navigation property will be lazy loaded
var server=entity.Server;
```

If you have disabled lazy loading you can load explicitly your navigation property using the `DbEntityEntry.Reference()`method:

```
//Load the Server navigation property explicitly
_context.Entry(entity).Reference(c => c.Server).Load();
```

Comment: So I would have to loop over all the rows in the results set? to load each item individually, which technically translates to 1 db trip per item?

Comment: @SOfanatic, those solutions are used when you need to load related entities using an specific entity instance. If you want to load all the data  in one db trip, then I suggest you translate your query to [linq to entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the `Include` extension method to load the related entities that you need as part of the query.

Comment: ok it seems like I'm stuck with the `.Load()` each entity individually because the `linq` query had to be changed to a `sql` query to improve performance.

Comment: @SOfanatic the DbSet.SqlQuery will add them to tracking when you raw sql query your db

Answer (score -1):

You can load all the rows for your navigation property first then load your main entity. Apply a filter on it first if you wish.

```
var servers = context.Servers.Where(m => m.ServerType == "Windows").ToList();
var mytable = context.MyTables.ToList();
```

or using SqlQuery

```
var servers = context.Database.SqlQuery<Server>("query_goes_here");

foreach (var serv in servers)
    context.Servers.Attach(serv);
```

then query MyTable and EF will link the two together for you