# How to bind relational data from SQL-Server to an Entity with one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using entity-framework6 with .net core. I was having some complex calculations to get some results from database so i created a stored procedure in database which gives me the list of properties as out put. I have successfully binded data to Property Object from database result. as shown below

**Stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PublicPropertySearch] 
    @Latitude float,
    @Longitude float,
    @Radius float = NULL,
    @HavePets bit = NULL,
    @FullBathroomCount int = NULL,
    @BedroomCount int = NULL,
    @RentPriceFrom int = NULL,
    @RentPriceTo int = NULL,
    @PropertyTypeId int = NULL

AS
BEGIN

declare @Geography geography = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Latitude , @Longitude , 4326);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select top 50 * from dbo.Property p
    --inner join dbo.PropertyFile f on f.PropertyId = p.PropertyId and f.IsPhoto = 1
    where GeoLogic.STDistance(@Geography)/1609.344 < @Radius
    and (@HavePets is null or p.HavePets = @HavePets)
    and (@FullBathroomCount is null or p.FullBathroomCount = @FullBathroomCount)
    and (@BedroomCount is null or p.BedroomCount = @BedroomCount)
    and (@RentPriceFrom is null or p.ExpectedRentalPrice > @RentPriceFrom)
    and (@RentPriceTo is null or p.ExpectedRentalPrice < @RentPriceTo)
    and (@PropertyTypeId is null or p.PropertyTypeId = @PropertyTypeId)

    --EXEC PublicPropertySearch @Latitude=28.609255,@Longitude=-81.250135,@Radius=5

END
```

**Code to bind result with entity**

```
var Properties = db.Database.SqlQuery<PublicPropertySearchResult>("exec PublicPropertySearch @Latitude, @Longitude, @Radius, @HavePets, @FullBathroomCount, @BedroomCount, @RentPriceFrom, @RentPriceTo, @PropertyTypeId", sp.ToArray()).ToList();
```

here is my property model

```
    class PublicPropertySearchResult
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int BedroomCount { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public double ExpectedRentalPrice { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string AreaUnit { get; set; }
        public int FullBathroomCount { get; set; }
        public string LandlordCurrency { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the output of my stored procedure

```
PropertyId  Title   Description Address StreetAddress   City    State   Country ZipCode Latitude    Longitude   HideStreetAddress   PropertyTypeId  ListingTypeId   Area    AreaUnit    BedroomCount    FullBathroomCount   HalfBathroomCount   Laundry IsFurnished HasParking  SitePaymentEnabled  TotalTenantsLiving  ExpectedRentalPrice HavePets                                                                    
163 3 Bed With Parking Features:(Assigned,Boat,Covered) Flooring: (Carpet,Ceramic Tile)     NULL    NULL    CASSELBERRY NULL    US  32707   28.636128   -81.320118  1   1   6   2811    NULL    3   3   0   Upper Level 0   1   NULL    NULL    220000  1                                                                       
234 4 Bed With Parking Features:(Other) Flooring: (Porcelain Tile)      NULL    NULL    WINTER PARK NULL    US  32789   28.599719   -81.331453  1   2   6   4715    NULL    4   5   1       0   1   NULL    NULL    1190900 0                                                                                                               
448 3 Bed  Flooring: (Terrazzo)     NULL    NULL    ORLANDO NULL    US  32817   28.609255   -81.250135  1   2   6   2016    NULL    3   2   0   Inside,Laundry Closet   0   0   NULL    NULL    415000  1                                       
515 3 Bed  Flooring: (Carpet,Ceramic Tile)      NULL    NULL    MAITLAND    NULL    US  32751   28.630359   -81.320365  1   3   6   NULL    NULL    3   2   1   Laundry Closet,Upper Level  0   0   NULL    NULL    269900  1
```

from this code i am only getting property object from Properties table now i also want to bind the Files object from PropertyFiles table in database (there is a relation between **PropertyFiles** and **Property** tables in database).

My question is what type of output requires from database to bind PropertyFiles object also. in the entity given below

```
    class PublicPropertySearchResult
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int BedroomCount { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public double ExpectedRentalPrice { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string AreaUnit { get; set; }
        public int FullBathroomCount { get; set; }
        public string LandlordCurrency { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PropertySearchFile> Files { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertySearchFile
    {
        public int PropertyFileId { get; set; }
        public string FileUrl { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public virtual PublicPropertySearchResult Property { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure?

Comment: i have modified the question

Comment: I only want to know, what type of output required from database to bind relational entity in entity-framework

Comment: Read this link I think its useful for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054887/loading-navigation-properties-with-raw-sql-query

Comment: @hassan.ef Let me try...

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify the 'one' part of the relationship, the 'many' part needs to contain the 'ones' identifier. Usually It's done like so:

```
public class PropertySearchFile
    {
        public int PropertyFileId { get; set; }
        public string FileUrl { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public int PropertyId { get; set; } //THat is assuming that PropertyId is the PK for the PublicPropertySearchResult class 
    }
```

Comment: ok then what should be the output of stored-procedure to bind this related **PropertySearchFile** object also. now i am only getting property table and it only binds property object